# I have 2 Different versions of nautilus installed somehow, How can I put the 3.6.3 version in the menu in GNOME Fallback?

Tags: gnome, updates, nautilus, ppa

I'm Using Ubuntu 12.10, I used the standard Gnome 3 ppa to update all the GNOME apps in 12.10 to version 3.6 **including** Nautilus. Then I realized that It didn't update *Rhythmbox* to version *2.98*, so I got the GNOME Shell ppa (Aka the "ricotz" testing ppa). Than I typed sudo apt-get update in the terminal, then I opened the Software Updater and no new packages were found. So I edit my sources list so that it would get the Precise testing packages. I ran sudo apt-get update opened Software Updater and installed all the updates. After this I went to change the ppa's file to get quantal packages and so I used sudo Nautilus (Note that this was AFTER all the packages were installed and system was restarted) and I got the 3.6 version. After I wanted to see a document so I opened Nautilus from the menu in GNOME Fallback and I was surprised that I got the 3.4 version! So then I went in the terminal and typed "sudo nautilus" and the 3.6 version showed up! So I had both the 3.4 and the 3.6 version on my screen!

So what I want to do is not remove the 3.4 version, but add an icon to the GNOME Fallback menu (Preferably under accesories) that will launch the 3.6 version as the 3.4 version does some things better and the 3.6 version does somethings better. (Note that the 3.4 version uses the nautilus %U command)

I was told to run some commands in the terminal and here is what I got
david@david-VirtualBox:~$ nautilus --version
GNOME nautilus 3.6.3
david@david-VirtualBox:~$ dpkg -l | grep nautilus
rc  libnautilus-extension1                       1:3.2.0-0ubuntu5                                   amd64        libraries for nautilus components - runtime version
ii  libnautilus-extension1a                      1:3.6.3-0ubuntu6~ubuntu12.10.1                     amd64        libraries for nautilus components - runtime version
ii  nautilus                                     1:3.6.3-0ubuntu6~ubuntu12.10.1                     amd64        file manager and graphical shell for GNOME
ii  nautilus-data                                1:3.6.3-0ubuntu6~ubuntu12.10.1                     all          data files for nautilus
ii  nautilus-sendto                              3.6.0-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        integrates Evolution and Pidgin into the Nautilus file manager
ii  nautilus-sendto-empathy                      3.6.0.3-0ubuntu1                                   amd64        GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client (nautilus-sendto plugin)
ii  nautilus-share                               0.7.3-1ubuntu3                                     amd64        Nautilus extension to share folder using Samba
david@david-VirtualBox:~$

It looks like the 3.4.2 version on the system is a bug.

Here are some images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should really update to a newer version of Ubuntu..

Comment: Are you sure that you have 2 version of nautilus? What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep nautilus`?

Comment: Also do `nautilus --version` for both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend that you remove the old version of nautilus, because it will remove ubuntu-desktop too. While ubuntu-desktop *is* a meta package, and nothing will explode immediately, there is a very good chance it will cause dependency issues later on.

[image]

Instead I suggest you upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu, either 13.10 or wait a couple of months for 14.04. In 13.10 I'm using Nautilus 3.8.